# Loop through Form Elements in the order they were added

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-form2

Zend Form 2 structures all Elements in Fieldsets. (Zend\Form\Form extends Fieldset - Form::add calls parent::add )

If i just add Elements to the Form i can get them via `$form->getElements()` if i use a fieldset i can get them via

```
foreach($form->getFieldsets() as $fieldset){
  $elements = $fieldset->getElements();
}
```

But imagine a form where i add a few hidden fields, then a fieldset, and at last a submit button.

How can i get the elements/fieldsets in their right order ?

Reason behind this, I'm working on a view helper which lets me print forms via a simple call to the view helper.

I don't want to call every form element via a call to `formRow()`
(I know of the concept behind Form2 - separating logic from presentation)

Any help is much appreciated.
TIA

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can do the following to get elements and fieldsets in the order they were added to the form:

```
/* $form is an instance of \Zend\Form\Form */
foreach ($form as $element) {

    // check if it's a form element or a fieldset etc.
    // and recursively iterate over elements of fieldsets etc.
}
```

Comment: ah thanks, so simple, i finally found where the IteratorAggregate Interface is set (in FieldsetInterface), but i dont find the current|next|prev methods for the iteration. so i never tried to directly loop over the object.